# Is it possible to obtain implementation details from a Project MetaDataReferences?

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

Having a Project p from a Solution s obtained through a MSBuildWorkspace, is it possible to have details of that project MetadataReferences (in this case it's a .dll), such as classes and methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project, call GetCompilationAsync() to get the compilation. From there you can look at the GlobalNamespace property which gives you the global namespace, and there you can walk to child namespaces and types from your code and all references merged together. If you want to walk types in particular references you can call GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol giving it a particular metadata reference, and then that will let you walk from there too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of obtaining the classes and methods through Micrososoft.CodeAnalysis Symbol Api, very inspired by [Kevin Pilch-Bisson](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2011/11/23/using-the-roslyn-symbol-api/) post in msdn blog.

```
private void GetSymbolsTest(ref Project project, ref MetadataReference metaRef)
    {
        if (!project.MetadataReferences.Contains(metaRef))
            throw new DllNotFoundException("metadatarefence not in project");

        var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
        var metaRefName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(metaRef.Display);

        SymbolCollector symCollector = new SymbolCollector();
        symCollector.Find(compilation.GlobalNamespace, metaRefName);
        Console.WriteLine($"Classes found: {symCollector.Classes.Count}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Methods found: {symCollector.Methods.Count}");
    }


public class SymbolCollector
{
    public HashSet<IMethodSymbol> Methods { get; private set; } = new HashSet<IMethodSymbol>();
    public HashSet<INamedTypeSymbol> Classes { get; private set; } = new HashSet<INamedTypeSymbol>();

    public void Find(INamespaceSymbol namespaceSymbol, string assemblyRefName)
    {
        foreach (var type in namespaceSymbol.GetTypeMembers())
        {
            if (String.Equals(type.ContainingAssembly.Name, assemblyRefName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                Find(type);
        }

        foreach (var childNs in namespaceSymbol.GetNamespaceMembers())
        {
            Find(childNs, assemblyRefName);
        }
    }

    private void Find(INamedTypeSymbol type)
    {
        if (type.Kind == SymbolKind.NamedType)
            Classes.Add(type);

        foreach (var member in type.GetMembers())
        {
            if (member.Kind == SymbolKind.Method)
                Methods.Add(member as IMethodSymbol);
        }

        foreach (var nested in type.GetTypeMembers())
        {
            Find(nested);
        }
    }
}
```

This way I don't need to use System.Reflection. Hope it helps someone sometime.

Comment: It's looks interesting and may be useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var mRef in project.MetadataReferences)
{
    Type[] assemblyTypes;

    if (!File.Exists(mRef.Display))
        continue;

    try
    {
        assemblyTypes = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(mRef.Display)
                                .GetTypes();
    }
    catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
    {
        assemblyTypes = e.Types
                         .Where(type => type != null)
                         .ToArray();
    }
    // ....
}
```

Comment: While it does work, is there anyway of doing it only using roslyn? I am exploring the SymbolApi but with no success yet.

Comment: There are number of problems with this: Display isn't guaranteed to be a path, and ReflectionOnlyLoads may not work in a lot of portable/cross targeting situations. See my other answer.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Thank you for the explanation.